<Loading/> not firing while replacing route with useRouter().push or replace but <Loading/> fires on reload page
In this nextjs-15 app router code, in <ControlButtons /> component when completed state changes, useRouter replace route with searchparams(/?completed=true), <Loading/> does not fire but when page is reload , <Loading /> does dire. What's wrong?
"use server"
const page = async ({
  searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
}) => {
  const params = await searchParams;
  const keys = Object.keys(params);
  const fetchUrl = `${process.env.BACKEND_URL}/tasks/?${keys
    .map((key) => `${key}=${params[key]}`)
    .join("&")}`;
  const session = await auth();
  const resCategories = await fetch(`${process.env.BACKEND_URL}/categories`);
  const categories = await resCategories.json();
  const resPriorities = await fetch(`${process.env.BACKEND_URL}/priorities`);
  const priorities = await resPriorities.json();
  const resTasks = await fetch(fetchUrl, {
    method: "GET",
    credentials: "include",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${session?.access}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  const tasks: TaskType[] = await resTasks.json();
  // TODO:Percentage on fornt of each task
  // TODO:Days to due date inside of each task
  return (
    <div>
      <Typography variant="h4" sx={{ textAlign: "center", marginTop: "1rem" }}>
        Tasks
      </Typography>
      <ControlButtons />
      <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
        <Task categories={categories} priorities={priorities} />
        <List
          sx={{
            width: "100%",
            bgcolor: "background.paper",
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            gap: "0.5rem",
          }}
        >
          {tasks.map((task) => (
            <ListItem


ControlButton:
const ControlButtons = () => {
  const params = useSearchParams();
  const router = useRouter();
  const currentCompleted = params.get("completed");
  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(currentCompleted == "true");
  useEffect(() => {
    router.replace(`?completed=${completed}`);
  }, [completed]);

  return (
    <Box sx={{ padding: "1rem" }}>
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "row",
          alignItems: "center",
          gap: "1rem",
        }}
      >
        <Typography>Completed</Typography>
        <Switch
          checked={completed}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setCompleted(e?.target?.checked);
          }}
        />
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};
export { ControlButtons };

I try and key={params.completed} to fire suspense but not works
